# Why CREATE TABLE AS SELECT is more faster than INSERT with SELECT

Tags: sql, oracle11g, sql-insert, create-table

I make a query with INNER JOIN and the result was 12 millions lines.
I like to put this in a table.
I did some tests and when I created the table using clause AS SELECT was more faster than, create the table first and run a INSERT with SELECT after.
I don't understand why.
Somebody can explain for me?
Tks

Comment: How much faster?

Comment: The create with AS SELECT runned in 12 minutes. The INSERT with SELECT runned in 50 minutes.

Comment: Did the existing table have any indexes on it? Or triggers on it?

Comment: Have you done the `INSERT ... SELECT` first and then the `CREATE ... SELECT`? Maybe the right pages just still were in the system buffer.

Comment: The tables used in the INNER JOIN have one field indexed. I'm use it in the where.
But, my question is about why the same query is more faster in the create table with clause AS SELECT blablabla than INSERT into TABLE SELECT blablabla.

Comment: The difference may have to do with logging, but it is hard (for me at least) to find differences in logging between the two approaches.

Comment: Is there also a huge difference if you try other queries? How many extents are created in both cases?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you use 'create table as select' (CTAS)

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS 
    SELECT * 
    FROM old_table
```

you automatically do a **[direct-path insert](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/admin/managing-tables.html#GUID-7ED50F3F-2BEB-4FDE-85B7-F8FB0D50FC66)** of the data. If you do an

```
INSERT INTO new_table AS 
    SELECT * 
    FROM old_table
```

you do a **conventional insert**. You have to use the APPEND-hint, if you want to do a direct path insert instead. So you have to do

```
INSERT /*+ APPEND */ INTO new_table AS 
    SELECT * 
    FROM old_table
```

to get a similar performance as in 'CREATE TABLE AS SELECT'.

**How does the usual conventional insert work?**

Oracle checks the **[free list](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:950845531436)**  of the table for an already used block of the table segment that has still free space. If the block isn't in the buffer cache it is read into the buffer cache. Eventually this block is read back to the disk.
During this process undo for the block is written (only a small amount of data is necessary here), data structures are updated, e.g. if necessary, the free list,that esides in the segment header and all these changes are written to the redo-buffer, too.

**How does a direct-path insert work?**

The process allocates space above the **high water mark** of the table, that is, beyond the already used space. It writes the data directly to the disk, without using a buffer cache. And it is also written to the redo buffer. When the session is committed, the highwater mark is raised beyond the new written data and this data is now visible to other sessions.

**How can I improve CTAS and direct-path inserts?**

- You can create he tale in NOLOGGING mode, than no redo information is written. If you do this, you should make a backup of the tablespace that contains the table after the insert, otherwisse you can not recover the table if you need this.
- You can do the select in parallel
- You can do the insert in parallel
- If you have to maintain indexes and constraints or even triggers during an insert operation this can slow down your insert operation drastically. So you should avoid this and create indexes after the insert and maybe create constraints with novalidata.

Answer (score 4):

With SELECT STATEMENT The table you create has no primary key, index, identity ... the columns are always allow NULL.
And It does not have to be written to the transaction log (and therefore does not rollback). It's seem like a "Naked Table".

With INSERT ... SELECT then table must be created before so when you create table you can define key, index, identity ... And it will use transaction logs
When applied to large amounts of data, it is very slow.

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand why the INSERT using SELECT clause is slow. For only information, my job to delete and insert in table 12 millions of lines run for 4 hours. It's time to fun and code a better code! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME PARALLEL AS (
Select col1, col2, col3
FROM TABLE_SOURCE);

--Additionally if you want to speed up this, you can
ALTER SESSION FORCE PARALLEL DDL PARALLEL 4;